# Contacts on Google Duo but not in contacts app

Tags: contacts

Many contacts there in Google Duo, but I can't find them in the contact app.

I've tried sync, but nothing appears, still on Duo only.
I've checked Google Contacts on the web, but with the same result, many contacts are not there.

Is there any way to move them from duo to my contacts?

Comment: Are you talking about the Google contacts app, or the contacts app that is provided by your phone manufacturer?  They are usually different and only synch with each other if you give them permiision to do so.

Comment: @Chenmunka I'm using Google Contacts